# How do I get if statements to print based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm working on a small text based game and I am stuck. I got my code to print the option but it prints it twice. Here is my code:

```
#options are presented here

a1 = "A. Inspect desk"

b1 = "B. Open door"

c1 = "C. Turn off lights"

print (a1)

print (b1)

print (c1)

ans1 = input('Type A, B, or C and press enter:')

option_1 = ("You find a notebook and a pen; there are illegible markings in the notebook.")

option_2 = ("You walk up and open the door. Some creature, vaguely humanoid, slams you into the ground and injects your arm \
with something. The creature leaves and you slowly lose consciousness…")

option_3 = ("You turn off the lights. Something or someone opens the door and peers in, it then closes the door. A moment \
passes and you believe the being is gone. You then walk about and encounter a hallway.")

dic1 = {"A": option_1, 'B': option_2, 'C': option_3}

for a in ans1:

    print (option_1)
```

This code currently prints option 1 twice. I'm not really sure how to format it so that it prints option 2 if user types in "B" and option 3 if they type in "C". Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I initially tried an if statement to no avail. A for loop at least printed option A, albeit twice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose value from dictionary i.e a, like this:-

```
#options are presented here

a1 = "A. Inspect desk"

b1 = "B. Open door"

c1 = "C. Turn off lights"

print (a1)

print (b1)

print (c1)

ans1 = input('Type A, B, or C and press enter:')

option_1 = ("You find a notebook and a pen; there are illegible markings      in the notebook.")

option_2 = ("You walk up and open the door. Some creature, vaguely humanoid, slams you into the ground and injects your arm \
with something. The creature leaves and you slowly lose consciousness…")

option_3 = ("You turn off the lights. Something or someone opens the door and peers in, it then closes the door. A moment \
passes and you believe the being is gone. You then walk about and encounter a hallway.")

dic1 = {"A": option_1, 'B': option_2, 'C': option_3}

print (dict1[a])
```

Comment: Hi, I am currently getting the following error with your method:
Traceback (most recent call last):File"PycharmProjects/Oblivion/Oblivion.py", line 45, in <module>
    print (dict1[a])
KeyError: ' '

Comment: should be dict1['A']

Comment: also you need to make it uppercase to get the input to be correct ..... so .......input('Type A, B, or C and press enter:').upper()

Comment: Thank you Asim and Johnashu, but it keeps printing twice with the new edits. Any idea of what may be going on here?

Comment: Oh okay, but wouldn't I need an IF statement? For example:
if ans1 == option_1:
   print(dict1['A'])

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a1 = "A. Inspect desk"

b1 = "B. Open door"

c1 = "C. Turn off lights"

print (a1)

print (b1)

print (c1)

ans1 = raw_input('Type A, B, or C and press enter:')

option_1 = "You find a notebook and a pen; there are illegible markings in the notebook."

option_2 = "You walk up and open the door. Some creature, vaguely humanoid, slams you into the ground and injects your arm \
            with something. The creature leaves and you slowly lose consciousness…"

option_3 = ("You turn off the lights. Something or someone opens the door and peers in, it then closes the door. A moment \
            passes and you believe the being is gone. You then walk about and encounter a hallway.")

dic1 = {'A': option_1, 'B': option_2, 'C': option_3}

print(dic1[ans1])
```

When the input is 'A':
[image]

When the input is 'B':

[image]

When the input is 'C':

[image]

Comment: Answer in python2.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not trying to just print one answer however. I want option 1 to print if the user input is 'A', option 2 if user input is 'B', etc. Would you know a way to do this? Perhaps an If statement?

Comment: What is the output from my program? This program satisfies your condition.

Comment: You can (and you **should**) paste the output instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it and it worked! Not sure why my Pycharm was being weird yesterday. The only thing was I changed  raw_input to input because I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Also the screenshots were quite helpful. Thanks again

Comment: Welcome borther @J. Torres

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works to print the options. if you type A or B or C, then you will get the corresponding options in the dictionary.

```
option_1 = "You find a notebook and a pen; there are illegible markings in the notebook."
option_2 = "You walk up and open the door. Some creature, vaguely humanoid, slams you into the ground and injects your arm with something. The creature leaves and you slowly lose consciousness…"
option_3 = "You turn off the lights. Something or someone opens the door and peers in, it then closes the door. A moment passes and you believe the being is gone. You then walk about and encounter a hallway."
dic1 = {"A": option_1, 'B': option_2, 'C': option_3}

ans1 = input('Enter type A, B, C\t:')
if ans1 in dic1:
    print(dic1[ans1])
else:
    print("Invalid Key")
```

The output:

```
Enter type A, B, C  :A
You find a notebook and a pen; there are illegible markings in the notebook.

Enter type A, B, C  :B
You walk up and open the door. Some creature, vaguely humanoid, slams you into the ground and injects your arm with something. The creature leaves and you slowly lose consciousness…

Enter type A, B, C  :C
You turn off the lights. Something or someone opens the door and peers in, it then closes the door. A moment passes and you believe the being is gone. You then walk about and encounter a hallway.

Enter type A, B, C  :a
Invalid Key
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Someone else helped me figure it out, but I'll keep this code in mind as an alternate method.